# Project level constants in swift

Tags: swift, enums, global-variables

I am new to Swift and coming from C/C++. I want some state constants to use in all files in the project. What is the standard practice to achieve this in Swift?

For example I need a state enum  --

```
enum ProgramState {
    case ProgramNotStarted
    case ProgramRunning
    case ProgramPaused
    case ProgramDone
}
```

Now I want to use this in multiple files in the project. In C you just add these to a header file and simply import them in every file you need the enum. How do you do it in Swift? I don't necessarily need a header file but simply want to achieve a similar functionality and code reuse.

Answer (score 0):

You can access your ProgramState enum like

```
let state = ProgramState.ProgramDone
```

Remember, state is `ProgramState` Type, if you want to access all cases as String then you need to define type to your enum, like below

```
enum ProgramState : String {
    case ProgramNotStarted
    case ProgramRunning
    case ProgramPaused
    case ProgramDone
}

let state = ProgramState.ProgramDone.rawValue
```

Now, you can access it's value as String